# mac os x openssl update error

Tags: macos, openssl

I need your help :)

I have mac os x 10.11.2,

And I have updated openssl library:

brew update
brew install openssl
brew link --force openssl.

After command "openssl version" I saw: OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
But after command "php -i | grep -i ssl" I saw:

OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 0.9.8zc 19 Mar 2015

And I can't install composer, get error: The OpenSSL library (0.9.8zc) used by PHP does not support TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.1.

How can I resolve it? It really strange...

Answer (score 0):

PHP and OpenSSL are also present in the Mac OS X system.

The fact that you have installed a second version via Homebrew does not mean it will automaically be used. you will need to make sure that composer finds the version provided by Homebrew (installed in `/usr/local/`).